# Shortest Path INSIDE a Polygon Algorithm/Pseudo Code

Tags: php, algorithm, polygon

I have a polygon (in PHP) represented by an array of X,Y points.  I wish to find the shortest path inside the polygon between point A and point B.  In practical terms, I have an arbitrary area, defined as a simple polygon, that I wish to know the distance through (e.g. think of it as a polygon representing a trail - I want to estimate how long the trail is).

Looking for pseudo code or some tips on where to get started.  I have scoured the internet and seem to be out of luck, other than some hard to understand papers on triangulation and funnel algorithms.

Comment: sounds like homework...lookup Insertion Sort, Mergesort on google

Comment: Why is this tagged java, php and c?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: what do these sorting algorithms have to do with path finding?

Comment: the idea of the question is the same, its about optimization. shortest route/shortest time to sort with given units/values. you dont really think your tutor wants to see code measuring 1 point to another?

Comment: Does your polygon have any particular characteristic, or is a completely general concave polygon?

Comment: @belisarus - either concave or convex, but always simple (never overlapping, no loops, no holes)

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone - Not homework, and poor suggestions.  This is not a MergeSort problem.  I am actually looking to measure one point to another, despite your incorrect intuition.

Comment: @Thrustmaster - It turns out Ted Hopp's answer has a great example, visually speaking.  Still working on understanding the funnel part of the algorithm though.

Answer (score 1):

A google search for *shortest path through polygon* turns up a lot of useful links. A nice description of one algorithm is [found here](http://www.geometrylab.de/ShortestPathLP/index.html) (complete with an applet animating the algorithm in action). Many of the algorithms are for a more complicated problem—one that allows for holes in the polygon. They can be used without change for your case of a simple polygon. (Actually, your problem can be thought of as the special case of finding a path through a general polygon, one in which all holes (obstacles) share a point with the edge.)

I think the best approach is an A* search through the space defined by the visibility graph of the polygon vertices plus the start and end points (if they aren't vertices already).

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm uses the fact that the path must travel from reflex vertex to reflex vertex (except for the first and last steps). So make the graph using all the reflex vertices and the starting and ending point, and use a standard shortest-path algorithm to find the shortest path. I have quite short Mathematica code that does all this, and will soon post a demo on the site demonstrations.wolfram.com. Send me a message if you want the code.